# Float div to bottom of containing div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I would like to position `id="des"` to the bottom of it containing `div`. I thought using `position:absolute` would work but it rather floating outside of the container.

```css
#links {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1 black;
  overflow: auto;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#des {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="links">
  <a href="/">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/social-bookmark/256/Feeds-icon.png" />
    <div id="des">FEEDS
      <br/>get latest updates here</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `position:relative` to `#links`

see more about position [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
#links {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1 black;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#des {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="links">
  <a href="/">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/social-bookmark/256/Feeds-icon.png" />
    <div id="des">FEEDS
      <br/>get latest updates here</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned with respect to their closest positioned ancestor, in your case the body. Setting `position:relative` on `#links` will however give you the behavior you're after:

```css
#links {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1 black;
  overflow: auto;
  position:relative;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#des {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="links">
  <a href="/">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/social-bookmark/256/Feeds-icon.png" />
    <div id="des">FEEDS
      <br/>get latest updates here</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position for more info on the position property.

Answer (score 0):

```
#links {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1 black;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/67166pyt/)

Answer (score 0):

both add position:relative to .des, but make your `height:auto` on #links if you don't want it to overflow  see [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvazGy)